# how to extract information in txt file using python

Tags: python, ascii

Here I have a data file in ASCII format, looks like this:

```
--Boundary--
ID     1234567
DATE   2/26/13
TYPE   X
CLASS  ABC
--Boundary--
ID     1234568
DATE   2/25/13
TYPE   Y
CLASS  DEF
--Boundary--
ID     1234569
DATE   2/24/13
TYPE   Z
CLASS  GHI
```

Now I need to extract the information of "ID" and "CLASS", i.e. I want some output file looks like this:

```
----------
ID          Class

1234567     ABC

1234568     DEF

1234569     GHI
```

The output file is also in .txt format.  I'm a beginner of python, any helpful script is greatly appreciated.

I tried the script:

```
inFile = open("input.txt")
outFile = open("output.txt", "w")
for line in inFile:
    if "ID" in line:
            id = line[line.find(' ')+7 :]
```

Is it a good way to do? How can I save the output?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're a beginner, this is a good way to learn about reading and writing files and how strings work in Python.  Did you read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) and try anything?

Comment: I tried the script -- inFile = open("filename") outFile = open("out.txt", "w") for line in inFile: if "ID" in line: id=line[line.find(' ')+7 :] -- this seems to work, but I don't know how to save it as outfile.

Comment: Please edit your code into the question itself instead of a comment-- it's easier to read there.  (Plus indentation matters in Python, and you can't really get that right in a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Is it a good way to do?
I will prefer this, but doesn't matter

```
id = line.split(' ')[-1]
```

2.How can I save the output?

from the tutorial,there you will find [7.2. Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
outFile.write(rowdata)
```

and don't forget outFile.close()

Comment: Thank you very much!  it works when I replace "rowdata" by "id", is it correct?  But the result shows the last data only.  In that example, only the last ID (i.e. 1234569) appears in the outFile.  Did I miss something?

Comment: outFile = open("output.txt", "aw"),RTFM... "'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending;" and for newline, add "\n" the end.